# Finding the integer that appears an odd number of times

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

Given an array of integers, find the one that appears an odd number of times.

There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times.

**My Attempt**

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  let newArr = A.sort();
  let altArr = [];
  let count = 0;
  let firstCharacter = newArr[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr[i] == firstCharacter) {
      count++;

    } else {
      let subArr = newArr.slice(newArr[0], count);
      console.log(subArr);
      altArr.push(subArr);
      count = 0;
      firstCharacter = newArr[i];
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < altArr.length; i++) {
    if (altArr[i].length % 2 != 0) {
      return altArr[i][0];
    }
  }
}


console.log(findOdd([20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5]))
```

**Problem**

I used console logs which showed me that the slices are returning an empty array Which I think is why this algorithm is broken. But why does it return an empty array? And is there any other mistakes i have missed?

Comment: The first argument to `slice()` is an array index. Why would you use an array element as the argument?

Comment: I'm not understanding why, logically, you need to slice.  Logically it would seem like you would just loop from 0 to n - 1, grab the element, and count how many times it occurs.  First one that is odd you would return it.  Nothing about that, to me, says I need to slice an array.

Comment: I was slicing so that I could take all of the ones that were the same  and group them for easy counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sorting, you could take a single loop and check the value against the last value (initialize without a value).

```js
function findOdd(array) {
    let count = 0;
    let last;

    array.sort();

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === last) {
            count++;
            continue;
        } 
        if (count % 2) return last;
        last = array[i];
        count = 1;
    }
    return last;
}

console.log(findOdd([20, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 20, 4, -1, -2, 5]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What does continue do?

Comment: "The [`continue` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration."

Comment: You missed THE solution, based on XORing. This is a classical trick.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes with this answer, the question is a duplicate. but op asks for the given code/appraoch.

Answer (score 6):

You are making this problem much more complicated than it actually is. A naive implementation would simply use an object to store the frequency of each element and then iterate over it at the end to find the element that appeared an odd amount of times.

```
function findOdd(arr) {
    const freq = {};
    for(const num of arr){
        freq[num] = (freq[num] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return +Object.keys(freq).find(num => freq[num] % 2 == 1);
}
```

A more efficient implementation could leverage the properties of the bitwise XOR (`^`), namely the fact that `a ^ a == 0`, `a ^ 0 == a`, and that the operation is commutative and associative, leading to the solution of applying XOR on each element of the array to obtain the answer.

```
function findOdd(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a,c)=>a ^ c, 0);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. XOR is so time and space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`newArr.slice(newArr[0], count);`
slice takes 2 parameters and they need to be index, not an actual value. So the above code is definitely not correct.
I think you can use dictionary to simplify this algorithm. Here is my approach.

```
function findOdd(A) {
    const appearances = {};
    A.forEach(val => {
        appearances[val] = (appearances[val] || 0) + 1;
    });
    const oddNumbers = Object.keys(appearances).filter(key => appearances[key] % 2 != 0);
    return oddNumbers.length > 0 ? oddNumbers[0] : NaN;
}
```